# Manual message order in Artemis Cluster

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm trying to achieve a load-balance in Artemis with Cluster but preserve the message order,but message order is a completely opposite concept than cluster,which means you should put producer and consumer in the same node all the time to preserve order,after I read the doc about [Cluster](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/clusters.html) and [HA](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ha.html), I found that with a manual control of producer could meet my needs.

Like what is told by the document, a load-balance strategy (along with a message redistribution) could always send messages to those nodes that have a consumer connected to, which means no matter which node the consumer connected to, it always can receive it.In this case, when I manually keep a producer connect to a specific node and a single consumer connect to a random node, the message order is preservered, correct me if wrong.

On the above primise, a node crash could break the message order.If a node and it's back-up node crashed(they are in a group) with messages left over, the consumer and the producer reconncet to another node, and then the crash node come back to live, those messages remained on it will be redistribute to the current node, it breaks the message order.

So, is there a way to turn off the message redistribution on the node initialization and restart it after a message purge(not a failover but a node completely crash situation), i konw it's quite strict.

Turn off the message distribution can solve this permanently, but the messages can no longer survive from a consumer connection change or failover.

With an external manually program to handle the load-balance and HA along with a bound producer-consumer pair might be useful, but cost a lots of work(it won't be as stable as Artemis).

A non-persistence message could be useful, but i don't think it would meet all kinds of situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, combining clustering with strict message ordering is a poor choice because the fundamental ideas of ordered messages and horizontal scaling through clustering are essentially at odds with each other.

Strict message order enforces *serial* message consumption (i.e. each message be fully consumed and acknowledged before the next message is consumed).

However, the idea of clustering is to scale brokers horizontally in order to increase message throughput by adding consumers which can process messages *concurrently*. Since the messages cannot be consumed concurrently this defeats the purpose of horizontal scaling.

You would almost certainly be much better off by simply using a single pair of HA brokers (i.e. one primary & one backup). A single instance of ActiveMQ Artemis can handle millions of messages per second in certain use-cases so even a single HA pair is likely to meet your performance needs.

There are lots of situations that would break strict message order in a normal cluster (some of which you have enumerated in your question), but since it really doesn't make sense to combine clustering with strict message order in the first place the broker hasn't been designed to deal with them. The closest you could get is by using [Clustered Message Grouping](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/message-grouping.html#clustered-grouping), but even that is not recommended for the reasons I've already outlined.

Comment: With much appreciate your answer enlighten me that with an order of message group that I can keep the message order no matter how many times the producer reconnect.I know it’s not appropriate to use cluster with message order, but this weird combination is needed in my case.Thank you again!